# How to get a list of customers that stopped paying this month based on last month payments?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following structure :

```
payments
 - id
 - created
 - amount
 - customer_id
```

This table contains values like :

```
'2016-12-03', 100, 1,
'2016-12-10',  50, 2,
'2016-12-23', 130, 3,

'2017-01-03', 100, 1,
'2017-01-11',  25, 4,
'2017-01-12',  50, 2,
'2017-01-24',  10, 3,
'2017-01-24',  25, 4,

'2017-02-03', 100, 1,
'2017-02-03',  25, 4,

'2017-03-03', 100, 1
```

(I've space the data for a better view, by months)

With those data in mind, I'm trying to build a MySQL query that would return me the customers that paid only once per month (aka subscriptions), at least two months, but that haven't paid the last month (up to 2017-02-03 as of today, but `(UTC_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)` in MySQL) (since March hasn't ended yet).

Using the above data, it would return `customer_id` 2 and 3, but I don't have a clue how to do it.

Please note that I'm also trying to do it on a rolling month basis (March is included up to today)

If it may help, the global idea is to get the customers that have stopped paying a recurring monthly payment.

I've made an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/570601) to help.

Comment: Can we see your best effort? Perhaps you've been able to solve one part of the problem, but not another part?

Comment: I'm trying to list the customers that have paid only once per month, and I'm having issues building this SQL query, so so far, I don't have anything working :/ (But I'm trying)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I'm going to start with a partial answer... customers who have made at least 1 payment per month in previous months...

```
SELECT customer_id
  FROM payments 
 WHERE created < DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01')
 GROUP
    BY customer_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(created,'%Y-%m')) > 1;
```

...with this core query, we can outer join last months payments onto that, as follows...

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM 
     ( SELECT customer_id
         FROM payments 
        WHERE created < DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01')
        GROUP
           BY customer_id
       HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(created,'%Y-%m')) > 1
     ) a
  LEFT
  JOIN payments b
    ON b.customer_id = a.customer_id
   AND b.created BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') - INTERVAL 1 MONTH AND DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01')
 WHERE b.id IS NULL;
```

Incidentally, the convoluted date comparisons are deliberate. Writing them this way allows MySQL to use an index on `created` (if one is provided)

Comment: That's really nice, and it solve 2 out of 3 of my problems : I'd like to remove the customers that paid more than once per month too (to keep only those who has a subscription), and this is the one that I'm stuck to.
Regarding your frst query (partial), I've changed the `WHERE created < DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01')` to `created BETWEEN (UTC_DATE() - INTERVAL 4 MONTH) AND DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01')` to list only the last 4 to 1 months back, not before (as its not necessary in my case)

Comment: wait ... I didn't tried your query because sqlfiddle was bugging, but I was able to try it again using MySQL now, and I correctly have the customer id 2 & 3 outputted, even though from reading your query, I was also expecting 4 to be outputed (as I don't see how you restrict the payments to one per customer). Could you enlight me ?

Comment: `LEFT JOIN x ON x... = y... AND x = 'z' WHERE x IS NULL` It's colloquially known as an exclusion join

Comment: Ok I'm stunned by the efficiency of your request! You rox!! Thank you very much !!

Comment: I've runned your query agains't my (real) database, and I've found some quircks. Specifically, if one customer did one purchase per month for more than two months, but months ago (lots of "months"...) it appears here. I only want the customers that also paid in january, but not in february `created BETWEEN (DATE() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH AND DATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)`. I've updated the fiddle to add the "error" entry, which is customer id 5 : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/570601

Comment: I was able to remove the customer id 5 from the results but by restricting the subquery to this : `WHERE created BETWEEN (UTC_DATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH) AND (UTC_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)` so of course I take the -3 and -2 months, and ensure there is at least more than 1 payment made, so it works, but I'd like to have that interval greater (ideally, just a "BEFORE") but I didn't find how to do it.

Comment: Could you please help me here @strawberry ?

Comment: I think you should edit your question accordingly - or ask a new question, but referencing this one.

Comment: I've updated the question accordingly last time, "but that haven't paid the last month" (this includes the fact they should have made a payment two months ago). If you prefer, I can ask a new question, just let me know.

Comment: I think a new question will get more attention. Provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements together with the desired result, and an explanation of why the present solution fails.